# How to change RTP media stream address in INVITE SDP using PJSIP?

Tags: c++, c, voip, pjsip

I'm working on some softphone application based on PJSIP and came accross such problem:
When application is running over VPN, my LAN interface address occurs in session SDP attributes, instead of VPN interface address, which is used by SIP to establish connection. As a result, after connection is established, side B is trying to stream RTP packets to unknown address.
Of course I can configure PBX to treat my application like it was behind NAT, to resolve that problem. But what I want to know: is there any clean way (not like modify SDP text before send) to set RTP connection address on application side? So when application is registered over VPN, it will be using address received by VPN network.

This is part of INVITE:

```
INVITE sip:someoneB@10.125.1.150:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.125.1.79:61589;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPja32fd2e9e5cc426cb0b44c973b620d8b
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:someoneA@10.125.1.150;tag=ca6940355e7f42f29afd2aa86add5c6f
To: sip:someoneB@10.125.1.150
Contact: <sip:someoneA@10.125.1.79:61589;ob>
...
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   432

...
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 0 9 96
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.107
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 192.168.1.107
...
```

My goal in this example is to set 10.125.1.79 address in SDP part.

How does PJSIP choose interface to media stream? How to change SDP attributes corresponding to RTP stream, during session? Is there some configuration or functions provided by library to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out, that setting an option `allow_sdp_nat_rewrite` of `pjsua_acc_config` structure to true resolves my problem. Now it's working as expected over VPN network.